# How can I let users use control + + for zoom in and control + - for zoom out?

Tags: qt, qml

The problem with my code below is that on US/UK keyboard layouts `+` is generated with `shift + =`, but when the user uses both the control and shift modifiers simultaneously, `+` is not generated. This has been tested on Mac.

```
    Keys.onPressed: {
        if (event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier) {
            if (event.key === Qt.Key_Minus) {
                zoom(false)
                event.accepted = true
            } else if (event.key === Qt.Key_Plus) {
                zoom(true)
                event.accepted = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Since `control + +` and `control + -` are standard shortcuts for zooming in applications I am certain that others have solved this. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Key.onPressed` use [`Shortcut`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shortcut.html) and its [`sequence` property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shortcut.html#sequence-prop) :

```
Shortcut {
    sequence: StandardKey.ZoomIn
    onActivated: zoom(true)
}
```

Your issue is mentionned in [this section](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#keyboard-layout-issues) of the QKeySequence documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Qt.ShiftModifier` for reacting on `shift` key:

```
Item {
    focus: true
    Keys.onPressed: {
        if ((event.key == Qt.Key_Plus) && (event.modifiers & Qt.ShiftModifier))
            console.log("PRessed");
    }
}
```

Comment: That will work for the US/UK layout, but it is not a general solution. It won't work for the Swedish layout where plus is on another key. I would ideally want a solution that does not require me to know where + is located on all keyboard layouts for all languages.

Comment: @user1283776 Ahh, ok, I see. I think this is not possible out of the box. You can give the user an option to configure keys for special functions.